# How to remove - when reading string values right to left

Tags: oracle11g, regexp-replace

I am creating new column based on right most values from existing values 
ABP-1-3-3 
CBP-1-10-12-14

Expoected values for new column i am able to read from left, Values i am getting

-3
14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7eew.png)

How can i modify my below code with regexp replace to remove any - ?

SUBSTR(TEST, -2, INSTR(TEST, '-')-1) AS TEST2,

Comment: If you are using python you just need to split it on - and take -1 why do you want to use regex for this?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mentioned its Oracle 11g

Comment: I am confused.  is " ABP-1-3-3 CBP-1-10-12-14" one row or two rows?  You want to get the values "3" and "14"?

Comment: ABP-1-3-3  and CBP-1-10-12-14 are two different values.                                      
          I am getting -3 and 14.      
                                                                                                                                      
             I want 3 and 14.

Comment: OK they are two different values, but are they in ONE row or two rows? Also, will the format always be the same?

Comment: they are in 2 different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with test as 
( select 'CBP-1-10-12-14' v1 from dual
  union 
  select 'ABP-1-3-3' v1 from dual
)
select regexp_substr( v1 , '[0-9]*$' )
from test
```

Also take a look at https://regex101.com/r/bS7hF5/1 . It is a neat site.  Put in your regex string, and it will "translate" it to human-readable description.

Comment: It does .. Thanks alot.